# Systemd: RequiredBy dependency is triggered even when failure occurs

Tags: systemd, services

I have 2 systemd services `test-dl.service` `test-db.service` that must be executed in a sequential order only when the first service succeed.

I'm using

- the `After` option to set a sequential order between the both services.
- the `RequiredBy` option to trigger the db service when the dl service succeed.

The RequiredBy/Requires documentation says
"If this unit gets activated, the units listed will be activated as well. If one of the other units fails to activate, and an ordering dependency After= on the failing unit is set, this unit will not be started."

However i observe the second service is started even when the first service fails.

My code snippet with the `test-dl.service`that fails and the `test-db.service`which is unexpectedly triggered.

test-dl.service

```
[Unit]
Description=The downloader.
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 10 ; exit 5'
```

test-db.service

```
[Unit]
Description=The parser.
After=test-dl.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exit 0'

[Install]
RequiredBy=test-dl.service
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This could happen if you didn't `systemctl install test-db.service`. Can you edit to clarify about that?

Comment: I'm using systemctl enable test-db.service